# How to work with getters and setters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Pure straightfoward question.

I code in Java and started learning Ruby not long ago. Got this question in my mind.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because No Effort. This is asking 'give me a beginners tutorial' as if the internet doesn't have beginner's tutorials on Ruby
“You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz
end
```

Based on what I know, I think it automatically sets getters and setters.  Just that you access it with the same name.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks!